# How to pass a view name to a stored procedure in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, view

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_HeatMap_Paper]
    @Grade varchar(150)=NULL, 
    @Site varchar(250)=NULL,
    @TRef varchar(15)=NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @uregref varchar(50), @regTID varchar(8),
            @testValue varchar(80), @testResultID int,
            @lowerL1 varchar(20), @upperL1 varchar(20),
            @lowerL2 varchar(20), @upperL2 varchar(20)

    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    BEGIN TRY
        DELETE FROM HeatMap;

    select top 1 @uregref = URegRef from NA_PAPER_HEAT_MAP where RSDESCRIPTION= @Grade and BOX_PLANT1= @Site;
    select @regTID = RegTID from REGKEY where URegRef = @uregref;
    select @testValue=TestResult,@testResultID=Result_ID from RESULTDATA where RegTID=@regTID and TRef=@TRef;

    SELECT @lowerL1=Lower, @upperL1=Upper from ResultLimit WHERE Priority = 1 and Result_Id=@testResultID;
    SELECT @lowerL2=Lower, @upperL2=Upper from ResultLimit WHERE Priority = 2 and Result_Id=@testResultID;


    Insert into HeatMap (Grade,Site,TestValue,TRef,LowerLimitL1,UpperLimitL1,LowerLimitL2,UpperLimitL2)
  values (@Grade,@Site,@testValue,@TRef,@lowerL1,@upperL1,@lowerL2,@upperL2)
    COMMIT TRANSACTION      
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        Return Error_Message()
    END CATCH
END
GO
```

I want to pass a view name into this stored procedure, here `'NA_PAPER_HEAT_MAP'` is the view instead of this I want to pass a parameter `@viewName`

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: This is usually a sign of a broken data model - if you have multiple tables (or here, views) with identical structures, it's often the case that they should instead be a single table (or view). Often accompanied by discovering that some of your *data* has instead become *metadata*, specifically it's embedded in the table name.

Comment: Your sp is named '...HeatMap_Paper' and is working with `NA_PAPER_HEAT_MAP ` and `HeatMap`. For any other views and tables create corresponding sp to work with them, e.g. `usp_Butthead_Beavis` to select from `NA_BUTTHEAD_STUFF` and insert into `BEAVIS_SO_ON`.

Answer (score 1):

You can build dynamic SQL and execute it using [sys.sp_executesql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) to execute it.
I'll give you an example for how to use it.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_selectView
    @id INT,
    @viewName NVARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX), @paramDef NVARCHAR(MAX);

    -- build dynamic SQL
    -- you can build whatever SQL you want. This is just an example
    -- make sure you sanitize @viewName to avoid SQL injection attack
    SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @viewName + ' WHERE Id = @selectedId';

    -- dynamic SQL parameter definition
    SET @paramDef = '@selectedId INT';

    -- here, execute the dynamic SQL
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql, @paramDef, @selectedId = @id
END
```